# C# PostSharp 4.1.32 Not runnable

Tags: c#, postsharp

i tried to get some customer software running and getting the Postsharp Build Messages: "Error connecting to the pipe server. See previous warnings for details"

See here error details:
    2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): warning : Connection unexpectly closed by the server.
2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): warning : Retrying to execute the pipe server.
2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): warning : Connection unexpectly closed by the server.
2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): warning : Retrying to execute the pipe server.
2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): warning : Connection unexpectly closed by the server.
2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): error : Error connecting to the pipe server. See previous warnings for details.

I think its related to this article:
http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2022-error-error-connecting-to-the-pipe-server

But I didn't found a solution that works for me on the web, I tried to disable postsharp and the code is buildable but then the aop features are missing on runtime so the dependency injection fail.

Important Note: Using PostSharp Express 4.1.32 / C# 4

What I have tried:

Set Postsharp for all platforms to x64 (No effect)

Change PostSharpHost to Native (Error Change to "2>C:\TEMP\packages\PostSharp.4.1.32\tools\PostSharp.targets(323,5): error MSB6006: "postsharp.4.0-x64.exe" wurde mit dem Code -1073741819 beendet.")

IgnoreErrors (Helps to build but not to run)

Downgrade to lower version (no effect)

Upgrade to newest version (no effect)

I know there a Problem with License System on Version 3, about a Nova Library but the postsharp version is outside of version range that was affected. Maybe delivered dlls are builded with older versions.

I have no experience on postsharp so it difficult to get the error/problem found.

I would be grateful to everyone that give me hints to search

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the build with Native Host:

`msbuild YourProject.csproj /p:PostSharpHost=Native`

See http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-msbuild.

Comment: Even with the most recent version?